# Customer Authentication between EE and CE

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, magento-enterprise, ee-1.12

I have a client asking to down grade from EE to CE. I have everything working except the client passwords. The admin passwords work fine but the client must reset their password.

Down anyone know if there is customer account login difference between EE 1.12 and CE 1.7?

I have confirmed my key is the same in the Local.xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magento EE is using sha256 as hash algorithm, while CE is only using a md5 hash.

You will have to reset all password as it's not possible to convert from one to another hash algorithm. Or you'll integrate your own password validation, which is than also using the sha256 algorithm instead of the insecure md5. ;)

Comment: Basically, write a module that converts CE password storage to EE. Make CE more and read the old passwords in one move. And since you have EE, unless they've cubed it, you have the source code.